# Google App Engine with Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I'm trying to use Google App Engine with Eclipse but it's not working.

I downloaded PyDev, and made a Hello World Python app, so that's working fine.

Then I created a new project, with the "Google App Engine" template. I was following these [instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html). I used the "Hello Webapp World" as a template, and didn't change any of the Python code. I added the GAE directory to my external libraries.

I then made a run configuration for my project, with the "Main Module" as the "HelloWorld.py" file I had created. I had one "Program Argument":

```
"${project_loc}/src"
```

Running this returns the following:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

However, if I launch this same app using the Google App Engine Launcher, it works fine. So what am I doing wrong in Eclipse?

Answer (score 6):

I've dealt with this same problem myself.

The Main Module needs to be set to the following:

```
${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/dev_appserver.py
```

It does cover it in the [instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html), step 3 under Starting Your First Project.  I must have glazed over it myself the first time as well.  Hope this helps!