# Unable to run python google app engine project

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am developing a tiny webapp on google app engine using python. 
I am using eclipse IDE for the development. When I tried to run the python webapp I am getting this error.

```
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: You might want to try downloading and installing [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  It will show you the HTTP traffic from your machine, so you might be able to debug this a little better.  Maybe the problem is a bit more obvious for google app engine users, but it is hard to tell why you're getting a 404 if we don't know what URL it is trying to retrieve, and don't have any of your code.  Also, maybe someone can tell you how to enable and retrieve logs, to try to debug this a little farther...

Comment: Are you running the app from the App Engine Launcher, or some other way? The launcher is the standard way to test it on your local machine.

Comment: When you run via `python devserver.py yourapp` and then go to `localhost:8080` do you get that 404 error? Have you got your templates proper? Show a bit of code or the example that you are trying.

Comment: Can you post the app.yaml and the (webapp?) url definitions for the app?

Comment: Since many people write webapps successfully, I think it's safe to assume this isn't a problem with App Engine. So, you should probably provide us with something that allows us to see what it is about your specific use of app engine is different - eg, your code and app.yaml.

Comment: I had the same problem. 
[Here's a link to the correct answer.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359550/google-app-engine-with-eclipse/2360476#2360476

Comment: I had the same problem. 
[Here's a link to the correct answer.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359550/google-app-engine-with-eclipse/2360476#2360476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably an error on the Eclipse side. Try using the launcher to run the application.